# Ubuntu on Ultrabooks

Tags: laptop, ssd, ultrabook

I've got a few questions targeting **Ubuntu** and **laptops(Ultrabooks)**:

How is Ubuntu supported on **Ultrabooks** at moment?

Is it recommended to go for a **Ultrabook** over a **normal laptop** considering it has to be kind of good for college and knowing that **SSD**'s are faster than **HDD**'s?

What's better, **SSD** only or the combination of **SSD** + **HDD**?

Answer (score 0):

using the **ultrabook** term is not precise enough to describe your specific necessity, since it allows for a really wide range of products, from the cheap to the expensive and bare-boned to the most featureful kind of equipment.

You'd better of asking questions about each feature you're interested in or about a specific model you choose. Try the askubuntu tag [filter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ultrabook) to sort out whether your question wasn't already answered.

About the **SSD** decision, it's basically whether you have the money and the care for such a speed up. Particularly I can't care less for a SSD drive, as long as I'm not developing SSD drivers nor running data servers.

Comment: Price differences are falling fast, and having at least the OS/kernel on ssd makes my zenbook as convenient a device as my tablet for quick web lookups and the like.